# Why can I not add null as a value when using ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

Consider the following code:

```
// holds the actual values
        private volatile ConcurrentDictionary<string, Object> values;

        public object this[string key] {
            get {     
                // exception is thrown on this line          
                return values.GetOrAdd(key, null);                
            }
            set {
                values.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (k, v) => value);                
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is simply create the entry in the dictionary if it does not exist yet; it should have no value though until something explicitly sets it. I get this exception though:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

The documentation states that key cannot be null, which makes sense. why am I getting this exception for a value though? Am I not understanding this method?

Comment: @sstan "Additional information: **Value** cannot be null."

Comment: @sstan That's what OP wrote.

Comment: Since the entire purpose of a dictionary is to allow using a key to lookup a value, it makes no sense to allow null values. If the key doesn't have a value, it doesn't belong in the dictionary, just like IRL a word doesn't belong in a dictionary until it has a definition. You don't find undefined words in the dictionary, do you?

Comment: @KenWhite `null` is totally allowed as a dictionary value.  See Alexei's answer.

Comment: @piedar: I didn't mean it wasn't strictly allowed. I meant what I said; it makes no sense to allow it, because a dictionary with a key and no value is useless by definition.

Comment: @KenWhite Sometimes you want to have the key ready and waiting for its value. When writing a real world dictionary, there is a short span of time where you have a word with no definition. It WILL get one, but it is a place holder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code ends up calling the other [GetOrAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes `Func` as argument (and it explicitly required not to be null - "key or valueFactory is null.").

```
public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key,Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)...
```

Fix: specify type explicitly:

```
 values.GetOrAdd("test", (Object)null);
```

Why: C# always tries to find more specific match and `Func<TKey, TValue>` is more specific than `Object` - so that override is picked.

Comment: If OP had used a more specific type for `TValue`, the compiler would have helped him by giving him the "call is ambiguous" error message.

Comment: Thanks! this make a lot of sense. casting to Object alleviates my immediate issue.