# ArgumentNullException in ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, .net, containers

I am getting some weird behavior when calling `AddOrUpdate` method of the `ConcurrentDictionary`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
    t.AddOrUpdate("boo", null, (k, v) => null);
}
```

throws `ArgumentNullException`:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: addValueFactory
  ParamName=addValueFactory
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory)
       at ConcurrentDictionaryTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Why? Am I not allowed to add `null`'s as values to concurrent dictionary? Documentation does not say anything special about `null` as value and following works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
    const object defaultValue = null;
    t.AddOrUpdate("boo", defaultValue, (k, v) => defaultValue);
}
```

So, what's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37951162/3874503

Comment: @rory.ap That's not true.  You can absolutely add null to a dictionary.

Comment: @BJMyers -- ahh well.  You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675(v=vs.110).aspx) for the overload you are using. The second argument is supposed to be a function invoked when the key doesn't exist. You're free to return null from this function, but you still have to provide it.

```
t.AddOrUpdate("boo", k => null, (k, v) => null);
```

If you want to use the [other overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use casting:

```
t.AddOrUpdate("boo", (object)null, (k, v) => null);
```